# How To change the Default Language?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-netbook, language-support

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my net book,by mistake i choosed wrong language not a english now i want to change my default language back to my loving English I tried to set english via language support tool but still by folder names display in other lanuage rather than english

Comment: Do you mean by folder names  your Nautilus Bookmarks like Videos, Documents, Pictures, Downloads,... ? If so, you would have to rename the folders by hand, because they wouldn't be affected by a change of your default language.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/130649/39372

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to System Settings -> User Accounts. The second entry is the user's language, you will be able to change it to english from there.

Comment: Thanks For comment i already did that but my folder names still dispkay ing Other Lang(Tamil)

Comment: try running 'gnome-language-selector' from the command line. It'll open up a graphical interface, which lets you set the language system wide. I don't know why the system settings wouldn't do that, though...

Comment: How to do this in bash?

Comment: When my PC randomly decided it was chinese, this fixed my problem - but you do have to guess that the first entry is "english"...