# Error upgrading to 13.04, "'ascii' codec can't encode character "

Tags: upgrade, 13.04

When trying to upgrade to 13.04 from 12.10, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 108, in <module>
    print(_("Checking for a new Ubuntu release"))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Does your username contains no-ascii characters?

Comment: No. It my user name is 'luis'

Comment: The problem was that the regional configuration was mis-configured. I do not know the reason, but it included a language Chinese-like language. I did not installed, and therefore it could not be uninstalled. What I did is to put it behind English.

Comment: @user2188463 If you think that your specifically problem was solved, please, create a new answer. That is more useful than be in a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here with upgrade from server Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04.
The solution which helped me was:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 do-release-upgrade
```

Original answer: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1278280/comments/9

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase the OP's comment, the problem was that the regional configuration was mis-configured. For some reason, the system was using a Chinese-like language. It wasn't installed manually, and couldn't be uninstalled either.  To fix this error, the system locale was changed.

See: 
[Some menus are in Chinese/Japanese!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130649/when-i-rebooted-12-04-certain-menus-are-in-chinese-japanese)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when upgrading from Xubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. I changed the system-wide locale from Finnish to English/USA, and the upgrade succeeded.