# How to open a PDF in dual page view, but for Arabic PDF's (Where pages layout should be from right to left)

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, evince, rtl

I have a PDF in the Arabic language. I've opened it with Poppler/cairo or Okular but I can't figure this out. I know this is so easy but I need help.

So Arabic books are normally from RIGHT to LEFT, so the page numbering is like this physically (ie how it should be):

```
PAGE 2 | PAGE 1
PAGE 4 | PAGE 3
```

But no matter what options in Okular or others, it comes out as:

```
BLANK  | PAGE 1
PAGE 2 | PAGE 3
PAGE 4 | PAGE 5
```

or...

```
PAGE 1 | PAGE 2
PAGE 3 | PAGE 4
PAGE 5 | PAGE 6
```

Can you help me? I'm so lost. Here is a sample PDF:
http://www.musily.usi.ch/documents/arabic.pdf

Can anyone figure out how to get dual-view to work? This will help me so much for my studies... Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems a bug, even with Arabic interface it does not flip pages order (Righ-To-Left). Consider reporting it upstream Okular Menu > Help > Report a bug. Or any program you want to use See https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: Ok, I sent them a message. Does Ubuntu have any other PDF Tools that may solve this problem? Can anyone advice me?

Comment: Man, I wonder if this is a Ubuntu or OS Problem then. Im not too familiar, but can you do something like `export lang=Arabic ; ocular myArabic.pdf` ?

Comment: It's an apllication problem. Even though I tried all them, only GUI interface flip (so already translated to Arabic). But the view (or more technically correct `canvas`) it's like drawing, the application should take care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Actually Acroread works.

  If you can't get it in software center, see https://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/otherversions/ . Download `.deb` package.

  Edit → Preferences → International → Enable Right to Left Language Options (Default can be change too)
- Qpdfview bug report (fix may be released with qpdfview 0.4.9)

  [lp bug#1281870](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qpdfview/+bug/1281870)

  From Menu, View → Right To Left
  Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
  To add it to toolbar: Edit → Settings → Interface → View Tool Bar: Add `rightToLeftMode` to comma separated list.
- Okular bug report (needs more votes)

  [kde bug#325650](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325650)
- Evince bug report

  [gnome bug#724704](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=724704)
- To test if the viewer may flip page layout too when launch with RTL (RightToLeft) local ie: RTL GUI, (ar_DZ for Algerian Arabic. Or prefer `ar.UTF8` as most application translated to single unified Arabic, no difference):

  ```
  LANGUAGE=ar_DZ.UTF8 acroread
  LANGUAGE=ar_DZ.UTF8 evince
  LANGUAGE=ar_DZ.UTF8 qpdfview
  LANG=ar_DZ.UTF8 okular
  ```

Comment: Best answer ever on Askubuntu.com. Thank you SO MUCH for this information. I hope that Okular and Evince get those supports soon. Thank you again SO MUCH, this is why I love ubuntu, because people are so nice and helpful.

Comment: @Bran, :) I hope so for evince/okular. qpdfview released the fix. it is already in the daily build of its developer (many thanks to Adam Reichold) [`ppa:adamreichold/qpdfview-dailydeb`](https://launchpad.net/~adamreichold/+archive/qpdfview-dailydeb). Even he made an upstream fix for Poppler to get direction property from pdf document. Poppler is used by evince/okular too.