# Would Ubuntu be installed with the current language of Windows 7?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, language-support

If I install Ubuntu on Samsung Notebook that is Formatted for Spanish will Ubuntu be in English which is preferred ?

If I install Ubuntu will I lose my pictures in Google Picasa ?

I am not real computer literate but tired of Windows.

Comment: DO you want to keep Windows?

Answer (score 2):

The language which Ubuntu is installed in is selected during the installation process and is not related to the language in which Windows is installed on that machine. It can also be changed after the installation process (which is not true of Windows generally).

Google does not have a Picasa app for Ubuntu, however there are many similar image management programs available in the "software centre" in Ubuntu. The pictures on your computer in Windows will be accessible from Ubuntu if you install Ubuntu alongside Windows. You will of course still be able to manage your Picasa photos online in Google+ if you do that currently.

Comment: actually there are clear steps how to run Picasa in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Ubuntu will allow you to choose which language you wish for your Ubuntu Install only. This selection won't affect other operating systems.

Your pictures in Google Picasa will be permanently deleted if you format (wipe) your current operating system and install Ubuntu as your only OS.

If you choose a dual boot, you will be offered to choose which operating system you wish to boot at the very moment that the computer attempts the start up.

See the answer to this question: [How can I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu) in order to check out how to install a dual boot OS.

You may wish to consider a dual boot previous to the full migration in order to face the transition with ease and be able to do certain tasks in your current operating system if you are in a hurry.

If you are heading to completely remove Windows in order to replace it with Ubuntu (which is a great idea, indeed), I suggest you to first make a full backup of those things that you don't wish to lose.

Additionally you may wish to consider that Ubuntu will offer you certain alternatives (a lot of them) for your current Windows based products. Picasa's alternatives will include (but not limited to) **[Shotwell](http://www.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/)** for the pictures management.

And my advice will be that if you migrate to Ubuntu, please try to think different and don't try to do things in the "Windows way". The tasks are easier in Ubuntu, we just need to get used to the alternatives when migrating.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

### Language

You can use whatever language and keyboard setup during Ubuntu install.

### Picasa

You can install Picasa in ubuntu under Wine (Windows emulation) and it works pretty well. It is enough if you just run the setup exe file in wine or there are better howtos fixing some photo upload troubles: ([How would I install Picasa 3.9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9))

Backup your database, especially if you have lot of data in recognized faces, places, photo comments etc.  You can use your old database and copy it to the new installation. Doublecheck, that you upgrade to the latest version of Picasa on Windows, so database can be transferred to the very same version in Linux/Wine. But this is not a straightforward process, so you will need some experience. Better would be, if you install ubuntu aside the Widoze, so you will have dual boot and you will be able to access windows files. Then you will be able to transfer the files, photos and picasa database and check that all is working. After you can free the space used by Windoze and use it for better purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your preferred language during the installation procedure.

Ubuntu will not recognize any language of other OS by their own.

Personally, I installed Ubuntu in English and then set Spanish for a *specific user*. You can do the same for any supported language and with all the users that you want to

---

Others question that will help you:

- [How To change the Default Language?](https://askubuntu.com/q/80746/62483)
- [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)